# Is it possible to use guards in function definition in idris?

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, idris, guard-clause

In haskell, one could write :

```
containsTen::Num a => Eq a => [a] -> Bool
containsTen (x : y : xs)
    | x + y == 10 = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Is it possible to write something equivalent in Idris, without doing it with `ifThenElse` (my real case is more complex than the one above)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Idris does not have pattern guards exactly as in haskell. There is **with** clause which is syntactically similar (but more powerful as it supports matching in presence of dependent types):

```
containsTen : Num a => List a -> Bool
containsTen (x :: y :: xs) with (x + y)
    | 10 = True
    | _  = False
```

You can take a look at the [Idris tutorial](http://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/writings/idris-tutorial.pdf) section **7 Views and the "with" rule**.

Comment: That's not the same as guards in the example Haskell which would allow for stuff like `| x+y == 10 ... | func (x * y + 52) > 42 = ...`.